# Internal Energy of an ideal gas with bounded momentum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas

Not a homework problem for me, but a situation I thought of while explaining population inversion to a couple of my students. I wondered if you could get a negative temperature ideal gas if the momentum $|\mathbf{p}|$ was somehow restricted to be less than some value $p_{max}$. I was able to derive a single particle partition function for such a system using the lower incomplete gamma function:
$$Z_{1}=\frac{4\pi}{h^{3}}\int_{V}^{}d\mathbf{x}\int_{0}^{p_{max}}dp\: p^{2}exp(-\beta \frac{p^{2}}{2m})=\frac{V}{h^{3}}\pi(2)^{5/2}\left ( \frac{m}{\beta } \right )^{3/2}\int_{0}^{\beta \varepsilon _{max}}du\, u^{1/2}exp(-u)$$
$$Z_{1}=\frac{V}{h^{3}}\pi(2)^{5/2}\left ( \frac{m}{\beta } \right )^{3/2}\gamma \left ( 3/2,\beta \varepsilon _{max} \right )$$
Obviously, taking the maximum energy to infinity nets us the familiar partition function for an ideal gas. Form here deriving the internal energy as a function of temperature seems straightforward$$U\left ( T \right )=-\frac{\partial }{\partial \beta }ln(\frac{1}{N!}Z_1^N)=-\frac{N}{Z_1}\frac{\partial Z_1}{\partial \beta }=-\frac{N\beta ^{3/2}}{\gamma \left ( 3/2,\beta \varepsilon _{max} \right )}\left ( -\frac{3}{2}\beta ^{-5/2} \gamma \left ( 3/2,\beta \varepsilon _{max} \right )+\beta ^{-3/2}\varepsilon _{max}\left ( \beta \varepsilon_{max} \right )^{1/2}exp\left ( -\beta \varepsilon _{max} \right )\right )$$
$$=\frac{3}{2}Nk_{B}T-N\varepsilon _{max}\frac{\left (\frac{\varepsilon _{max}}{k_{B}T}  \right )^{1/2}exp\left ( -\frac{\varepsilon _{max}}{k_{B}T} \right )}{\gamma \left ( 3/2,\frac{\varepsilon _{max}}{k_{B}T} \right )}$$
Which seems sensible. As $\varepsilon_{max}$ approaches infinity, the second term goes to zero and we recover the familiar internal energy of an ideal gas. However, my concern is that while graphing this the energy seems to be bounded for large T, I am having difficulty actually evaluating the internal energy in that limit. I would expect the value to be $N\frac{\varepsilon_{max}}{2}$, but graphing it shows a solution of $N\frac{3\varepsilon_{max}}{5}$. I may just be very tired but I can't see an obvious way to get this result. Any ideas?

Comment: This should boil down to essentially the same calculation as the ground state energy of a Fermi gas, with $\varepsilon_{max}$ replaced by the Fermi level and from memory the result is something like a factor of 3/5. Your intuition that it should be 1/2 is missing a density of states factor: the number of microstates with total momentum $p$ is proportional to $4\pi p^2$ in 3D and the mapping from momentum to energy states introduces a factor of $1/2p$, so the net result is there are more states with a high energy than a low energy